# Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone

When i click on done button which has code

```
UIBarButtonItem * button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                          target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=UIBarButtonSystemItemDone;
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];
[button release];

-(void)dismissView: (id)sender

{

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

application crashes and gives message Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Any ideas what is wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Post the backtrace, or at least which line is causing the error.

Comment: Hard to tell without some more context, but it would seem that you might be double releasing your button. You call autorelease on it, and then you also call release on it. Since you haven't incremented the ref count, but calling retain only one of those is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is entirely wrong:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=UIBarButtonSystemItemDone;
```

Remove it. You are setting the `rightBarButtonItem` right after that and also, you can't set the `rightBarButtonItem` to `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` - that just doesn't make any sense at all.

Oh and you're overreleasing `button`. Remove the `[button release];` as well.

Comment: Thanks mattjgalloway that message is gone but now it is not navigating back to main window as per dismissview method. Basically nothing happens when done button is pressed.

Comment: Is your method being called? Stick an `NSLog` in there to see.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-releasing your button. You autorelease it when you alloc/init and then release it again after setting it as the nav item.

Answer (score 1):

You’re over-releasing `button`. Its `+alloc` call on the first line is already balanced by the `-autorelease` on that same line—you don’t need to call `-release` on it thereafter.

Comment: Thanks mattjgalloway that message is gone but now it is not navigating back to main window as per dismissview method. Basically nothing happens when done button is pressed.